# How to reference the data URL of an (already) uploaded image file and pass it to another function upon button click?

Tags: javascript, image, asynchronous, callback

I used File Reader to generate img tags when there are changes to file input and render thumbnails by passing in the data URLs to the img src. However, when I try to access these img tags later (during another Submit button click), they are always undefined.

After looking up many answers to similar questions, I realise that it's because of the asynchronous nature of the readAsDataURL(file) function. So now, instead of trying to reference the data URLs from the img src, I'm running File Reader again in my submitForm(), hoping to get the callback and process the dataURLs in submitForm(). I can't immediately run the submit after loading my image files either because there are other form details that need to be filled in.

This seems a bit silly to me, not to mention it isn't working :( (probably because of the .onloadend, given that the files are already loaded!). Is there a better way to (1) retrieve the data URLs from my previously loaded img src? or (2) perhaps a totally different approach?

I'm quite new to javascript callbacks and am reading and learning as much as I can from online tutorials and examples and I beg your pardon if my question sounds dumb.

```
var fileReaderURL = function(callback){
    const files = document.getElementById("file-input").files;
    var dataURL;
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        if(files[i]){
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
            dataURL[i] = reader.result;
        }
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            dataURL[i] = reader.result;
        };
    }
    callback(dataURL);
    console.log(dataURL);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing, I just managed to retrieve the img data URLs from the loaded files using simple document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail'). Probably something else I did wrong the previous time round caused the undefined error. Apologies for the question!